# Deleting realm DB objects, but even if all objects are empty, the realm file size remains the same. and in time becomes way too big

Tags: android, database, realm, storage, realm-mobile-platform

I have a realm database that I use inside my app.
The size of the file is 7mb. It has different objects inside.
But then I call this function:

```
 public static void deleteRealm(Context context) {
    Realm realm = PSApplicationClass.getInstance().getRealm();
    try {
        Log.i("", "realm start");
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.delete(Destination.class);
                realm.delete(TripStep.class);
                realm.delete(TripStop.class);
                realm.delete(Route.class);
                realm.delete(RealmLocation.class);
                realm.delete(CoordLocation.class);
                realm.delete(PSTrip.class);
                realm.delete(PSUser.class);
                realm.delete(UserVehicle.class);
                realm.delete(Vehicle.class);
                realm.delete(MileageRates.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityMonth.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityWeek.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityYear.class);
                realm.delete(Activity.class);
                realm.delete(PSTripsStats.class);
                realm.delete(Report.class);
                realm.delete(Setting.class);
                realm.delete(AddressComponent.class);
                realm.delete(RealmString.class);
                realm.delete(RealmInt.class);
                realm.deleteAll();
            }
        });
        Log.i("", "realm end");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("", "realm continue initTrip error trying to add to realm:" + e.getMessage());
        if (realm.isInTransaction()) {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

And I check again. and the file has still 7 MB, but it is empty. no realm objects inside.
Even more, if I get the same data again, it will grow to 14MB, so when I delete the data, it will have 14MB empty, and then grow to 21... and so on. Which causes it to become a huge file. And I'm pretty sure this should not happen. why does realm do this?
This is the file that I'm talking about:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri95yiwjutjiki6/myrealm.realm?dl=0

Comment: normally it is caused by unclosed Realm instance on the background thread. Do you have any Realm instance opened on the background thread and it is not closed when the thread terminated? Take a look at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq-large-realm-file-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Realm FAQ](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq-large-realm-file-size), this is to be expected, and database will reuse the space eventually.

That being said, you could force a database compaction by calling `Realm#compactRealm(RealmConfiguration)`. See [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-).

Comment: Ok. but still, I got a user who user this app for more than a year, and noticed that our app was using 6GB of data, cause of this. That is a lot.

Comment: I can just suggest to either add the `Realm#compactRealm(RealmConfiguration)` after deleting all the entries. I don't know about this specific user, but this would look like a bug. An alternative (or additional) option will be to schedule a compaction of the database when device is connected to the charger (usually during night time), by using `JobScheduler` (or Firebase JobDispatcher if you need pre-5.0 compatibility https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android ).

Comment: I'm now using compact Realm, had to modify my code, because I had some  instances of Realm that we're open from another thread, and not closed properly, but now this works. Upvoted and accepted your answer

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks!

Comment: @rosualin I think you should post what worked for you to be of help to others.